# WebClient.DownloadData Progress Report

Tags: .net, vb.net, progress-bar, webclient, backgroundworker

I have a BackgroundWorker to download an image file and view it in a PictureBox.
I want to report the progress of that download (since it could be a large image file) and update a ProgressBar. It seems I can't find a proper way to do it.

I found [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.downloadprogresschanged?view=netframework-4.8) article in Microsoft documentations but it only contains C# usage. Anyone could point me in the right direction?

My actual code inside the BackgroundWorker:

```
Private Sub BackgroundWorker3_DoWork(sender As Object, e As DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker3.DoWork
    Dim Test1 As String = "DOWNLOAD URL"
    Dim tClient As WebClient = New WebClient
    Dim tImage As Bitmap = Bitmap.FromStream(New MemoryStream(tClient.DownloadData(Test1)))
    PictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom
    PictureBox1.Image = tImage
End Sub
```

I guess it would be something like the ReportProgress from BackgroundWorker, but can't understand how to apply it into download data since I don't know the actual file size:

```
ReportProgress(Convert.ToInt32((contagem / count) * 100))
```

Comment: See the [WebClient.DownloadDataAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.downloaddataasync) method. The download process raises the [DownloadProgressChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.downloadprogresschanged) event, which also provides the progress percentage. Btw, the BackGroundWorker doesn't, well, *work*, like that. Almost all those objects cannot be used in the `DoWork` event in that manner.

Comment: ***I found this article...*** You can select VB.NET from the language drop down list in that page.

Answer (score 0):

As Devs in comments says, an efficient way to download data in async mode might be this one:
There is two Events, one for progress and the other on end of download.
I put together some code as a base you can start improving. 
Hope was this your target :)

```
Event OnDownloadCompleted(downloadedDataAsByteArray() As Byte)
Event OnDownloadProgress(percentage As Integer)

Private Sub DownLoadFileAsync(address As String)

    Dim client As Net.WebClient = New Net.WebClient()

    AddHandler client.DownloadDataCompleted, Sub(sender As Object, e As System.Net.DownloadDataCompletedEventArgs)
                                                 RaiseEvent OnDownloadCompleted(e.Result)
                                             End Sub

    AddHandler client.DownloadProgressChanged, Sub(sender As Object, e As System.Net.DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs)
                                                   RaiseEvent OnDownloadProgress(e.ProgressPercentage)
                                                   Application.DoEvents()
                                               End Sub

    Dim uri As Uri = New Uri(address)
    client.DownloadDataAsync(uri)

End Sub
```

Usage

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    AddHandler Me.OnDownloadProgress, Sub(percet As Integer)
                                          Console.WriteLine("Percent reiceved: " & percet.ToString)
                                      End Sub


    AddHandler Me.OnDownloadCompleted, Sub(data() As Byte)
                                           Console.WriteLine("Download completed, total: " & data.Count)
                                           Using mStream As New MemoryStream(data)
                                               'Do what you want with this image
                                               Dim image As Image = Image.FromStream(mStream)
                                           End Using
                                       End Sub


    DownLoadFileAsync("https://images.pexels.com/photos/3952233/pexels-photo-3952233.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=3&h=750&w=1260")

End Sub
```